# Laravel: use execute-on-server instead of redirect

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

We know that if we use `return redirect('some_url')`, the server will return `302` thus the client have to request the new url again. This is very low.

So I wonder whether these is a function that works like this: "`return execute('some_url')`", and the server response is exactly **the same** as what we get when we visit the `some_url`.

The more concrete usages: (The execute function is what I want)

```
public function index(){
    if(Auth::check()){
        return execute('url1');
    }else{
        return execute('url2');
    }
}
```

I would appreciate it if anyone could give me some advice!

Comment: are your trying to execute a view and return the response to that view to the user?

Comment: @SaadBhutto I don't think it can be of great use... What about all the middlewares, controllers and so on?